# SQL Query Alias Explanation

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, alias, procedure

I am having an issue running this query. It is supposed to be stored as a procedure which is what I am doing. What I can't figure out is what a couple of the aliases are referring to.

**Link To Full Source:** http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

**Code:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE geodist (IN userid int, IN dist int)

BEGIN

DECLARE mylon double;
DECLARE mylat double;
DECLARE lon1 float;
DECLARE lon2 float;
DECLARE lat1 float;
DECLARE lat2 float;

SELECT longitude, latitude into mylon, mylat from users WHERE id=userid limit 1;

SET lon1 = mylon-dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
SET lon2 = mylon+dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
SET lat1 = mylat-(dist/69);
SET lat2 = mylat+(dist/69);


SELECT destination.*, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig.lat -dest.lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(orig.lat * pi()/180) * COS(dest.lat * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((orig.lon -dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance FROM users destination, users origin WHERE origin.id=userid
and destination.longitude between lon1 and lon2 and destination.latitude between lat1 and lat2 
having distance < dist ORDER BY distance limit 10;

END
```

> **The Issue I Am Having:** In the actual select statement it almost
>   immediately refers to orig.lat and dest.lat, also orig.lon and
>   dest.lon. I can't find these references anywhere. What are these
>   referring to?

**When I try to run this query I get an error:**

> "Unknown Column orig.lat"

Comment: since 'origin' is an alias for the table 'users', my guess is that 'orig' should be 'origin'

Comment: I tried changing that, now i get the error #1054 - Unknown column 'origin.lat' in 'field list' which is the same as before. Thankyou for you help, btw!

Comment: Simple fix, I got it, THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables are aliased as destination and origin at `users destination` and `users origin`.

Presumably, you want to replace `orig.lat -dest.lat` with `origin.lat -destination.lat`. You would also do the same with the other references.

Comment: I get the error #1054 - Unknown column 'origin.lat' in 'field list' which is the same as before, thanks for your help, btw!

Comment: Simple fix, I got it, Thanks for the help!